# Does the z-index affect the linear background?

Tags: html, background-image, z-index

Here's my code:

```
#Bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(Aquamarine, Lavender);
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

AboutMy dogsBibliographyHome

For some reason the `background-image: linear-gradient(Aquamarine, Lavender);` won't work.

Instead it just shows a transparent background for the bar. This piece of code is for the navigation bar on my website.

Is this because of the z-index? Or some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `width: 100%;` for example in your css because when you make it fixed it collapse when you have no width set.

Comment: I tried  #Bar{background-image: linear-gradient(Aquamarine, Lavander);
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 3;
        position: fixed;
        margin: 0px;
    }

Comment: how do you make a certain part of your question/comment in that code format? I'm new to stack overflow and I can't figure it out.

Comment: While just select what you want to be code and than click this button above { } but this only works in answers not in commends.

Comment: How do I add to your reputation? What do I click? Btw do you have any other ideas to fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(Aquamarine, Lavender);
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">&nbsp;</div>
```

This worked fine for me. Just make sure to add `&nbsp;` between the tags.